# Hide toggle calendar button on Kendo Angular DatePicker

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I would like to use a Kendo Angular `DatePicker` and **move the "Toggle calendar button" to else where** (a floating toolbar). That's why I don't use a `DateInput` control.
I try to hide the toggle button within the input by css, but this doesn't works:

```
  .k-select {
    display: none;
  }
```

Even if this jquery command in the browser console works :

```
$('.k-select').css('display','none')
```

How can I do that?
I there another way to move this button.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with ViewEncapsulation, see example below:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <style>
    .k-datepicker .k-select {
        display: none;
      }

      .k-datepicker .k-picker-wrap {
        padding: 0;
      }

      .k-datepicker .k-input {
        border-radius: 3px;
      }
    </style>

        <div class="example-wrapper" style="min-height: 400px">
            <p>Select a date:</p>
            <kendo-datepicker
                [(value)]="value"
            ></kendo-datepicker>
        </div>
    `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {
  public value: Date = new Date(2000, 2, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't works. It works when I call `$('.k-select').css('display','none')` in the browser console, but the CSS doesn't work.

Comment: I got it working now with ViewEncapsulation, see my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Ok it works. But how to know the implication of the change? Does this change will break my app design somewhere?

Comment: I finally found a way to do it without changing the behaviour of the whole component. See my answer.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use the `::ng-deep` pseudo-class selector to access the element.

**your_component.scss:**

```
::ng-deep .hiddenCalendarControl .k-select {
  display: none;
}
```

**your_component.html:**

```
<kendo-datepicker
  class="hiddenCalendarControl"
  ...
></kendo-datepicker>
```